# Wordpress - Load pages filtering by parents id and taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get the custom posts from a specific parent id and taxonomy.

I'm using this code, and I'm getting ALL the posts that are a child of the ID, but the taxonomy filter isn't affecting

```
<?php
$posts_array = get_pages(
    array(
    'post_type' => 'recetas_membresia',
    'child_of' => $id_padre,
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(                                                          
    'taxonomy' => 'comidas',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $comida->slug
    ))                                                                   
));

foreach ($posts_array as $post ) {;?>
<li><?php echo $post->post_title ;?></li>

<?php } ;?>
```

---

I have been tried to use compare in the query but still having the same result.

How can I get these specific posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `get_pages` [function reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/) I can't see that `tax_query` would work here. (as it seems to work differently than all the other **Post** related functions. And I personally never used `get_pages`)

What you want to use is `get_posts` ([ref](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/)).
Instead of `child_of` you'd use `post_parent` then to get the children, as listed in the `WP_Query::parse_query` [ref](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Query/parse_query/).

```
$posts_array = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'recetas_membresia',
        'post_parent' => $id_padre,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(                                                          
                'taxonomy' => 'comidas',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $comida->slug
            )
        )                                                                   
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
posts_array = get_pages(
    array(
    'post_type' => 'recipes',
    'child_of' => $id_parent,                                                               
    'tax_query' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'food',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $food->term_id
    )                                                                       
));
```

Comment: Edited just now the answer, you need to use tax_query, read too fast and not saw that

Comment: I don't think that's correct. If `tax_query` was working with `get_pages` then it'd probably be working like everywhere else. As an *array of arrays* like seen in this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49185/tax-query-parameter-not-working-with-wp-query